# Prepend/Append a div offscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a div that has two buttons: one to prepend a div of the same size to the right of the original **without shifting the position of the original div** and another button to append a div to the right of the original.

Appending to the left works fine, but prepending left shifts the whole container over [shown here](http://codepen.io/jxpei/pen/XbawxO)

code I'm using to add elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#back").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#center").before("<div id='back' class='inside'></div>");
  });
  $("#next").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#center").after("<div id='next' class='inside'></div>");
  });
});
```

How do I prepend the div left of the original so that it is "off screen" without shifting the position of the original div? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like something that could be solved with CSS rather than JS - perhaps share your markup?

Comment: There's a codepen link in the original post (http://codepen.io/jxpei/pen/XbawxO). How would I achieve this effect using pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is best solved using CSS.

Simply set `display:none` to the left DIV upon initial insertion.

Change this:

```
$("#center").before("<div id='back' class='inside'></div>");
```

To this:

```
$("#center").before("<div id='back' class='inside' style='display:none;'></div>");
```

And remove that CSS attribute when you want it visible:

```
$('#back').css('display', '');
```

However, the use of inline styling is, in most cases, bad practice. You should consider setting the `display:none` via a stylesheet assigned to the element ID `#back`. For maintainable code, you want to keep clear separation of style (CSS), structure (HTML) and UI functionality (JS).

Comment: Thank you! I'll move forward with trying display:none;

Answer (score 0):

try to set the following CSS for the containing div

```
div.whatever {
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}
```